# UWP - Give button a random location

Tags: c#, uwp

In UWP i would like to give my button a random location on my screen when it is clicked on.

My code looks like this:

```
    private void DeclareHere()
    {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        int iRndX = randomGenerator.Next(1, 640);
        int iRndY = randomGenerator.Next(1, 360);

        btnRandom.Margin.Left.Equals(iRndX);
        btnRandom.Margin.Top.Equals(iRndY);
    }

    private void btnRandom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DeclareHere();
    }
```

What is it that i'm missing? Would help if you could explain how you accomplished the solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Equals** is just a comparison **operator**.

ex:

```
bool isEqual = btnRandom.Margin.Left.Equals(iRndY);
```

You need to **assign** margin values

So, you should change this:

```
    btnRandom.Margin.Left.Equals(iRndX);
    btnRandom.Margin.Top.Equals(iRndY);
```

with this:

```
 btnRandom.Margin = new Thickness { Left = iRndX, Top = iRndY};
```